# Как нажать на кнопку с названием класса в 116 символов Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Я сейчас пытаюсь авторизоваться в хорме но когда я ввел свою почту и мне надо нажать кнопку далее. Я прикрепил фото со свойствам кнопки. Единственное что мне подходит чтобы ее достать это название класса, но когда я полностью вставил в код мне выдало ошибку, мол селениум не нашел такой объект. Пытался нажать на див ну как не странно это не работает.
Прошу помощи у опытных разработчиков в этом деле как решить данную задачу. Вот тег:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: еще бы пример кода

Comment: сейчас добавлю.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поставить ожидание (wait until clicable) чтоб кнопка загрузилась, ибо код выполняется быстрее, чем элемент появляется на странице. Либо вообще прямо влоб - time(10) и PyAutoGUI, если уж вообще туго искать.